# The primary selection criteria for choosing FM vs. AM is dynamic range

Tags: frequency-modulation, amplitude-modulation

The primary reason for selecting FM over AM is the ability of FM to support a greater dynamic range by spreading the information across a wide range of frequencies, and using more 'horizontal information carrying capacity'.

Trying to increase the dynamic range of an AM signal would require impractical levels of power to be used to represent the same information carrying capacity in a 'vertical' or amplitude modulated scenario?

Yay or nay.

Comment: The monaural FM signal that we’ve used since 1938 is capable of delivering static-free audio from 50 Hz to 15,000 Hz. Unlike the AM signal, which is easily overmodulated, FM has a wide dynamic range. Each station can deviate ± 75 kHz from its center frequency – in other words, if you tune in a station at 97.1 MHz, a 1 kHz tone at maximum volume would make that frequency vary by plus or minus 75 kHz.  So 1,000 times per second, the carrier wave would sweep up to 97.175 and down to 97.025. There’s also a 25 kHz guard band at each end, giving that station at 97.1 a 200 kHz spectrum of 97-97.2MHz.

Comment: http://www.museumofbroadcasting.org/fm/fmstereo.html

Answer (score 1):

There is no fundamental reason why AM cannot support the same dynamic range as FM.  You can vary the amplitude of a carrier over as wide a range as you can deviate its frequency.  The fundamental limitation on dynamic range of any information carrying medium is noise. In this respect, FM can be superior to AM but the tradeoff is bandwidth.  An FM signal will have a better signal-to-noise ratio than AM (hence the better performance of commercial FM broadcasts than AM) but at the cost of greater bandwidth. Sending a 1 kHz signal with AM requires a bandwidth of about 2 kHz.  Using commercial FM requires about 150 kHz. You can't get something for nothing.

Comment: just so I'm clear, by varying the amplitude of a carrier, you mean you can vary the amplitude of the energy content of any infinite frequencies in the bandwidth of an AM signal.

Comment: By varying the amplitude of the carrier with the modulating signal, you are transferring the frequencies contained in the modulating signal around the carrier frequency.  The resulting spectrum on each side of the carrier is identical to the spectrum of the modulating signal.  There are no infinite frequencies.

Comment: To what extent is the poor noise performance of typical AM receivers a fundamental limitation of AM modulation, and to what extent is it a result of receiver designs which will alias many "junk" frequencies to audio frequencies?  If a receiver is tuned for 1Mhz, the only frequencies that should alias to 1Khz should be 1.001Mhz and 0.999Mhz, but by my understanding many tuners use summing and rectification to alias modulated frequencies to audio, and such techniques may alias other unwanted frequencies as well.

Comment: @supercat It isn't a limitation of the modulation, it is a limitation of the medium. Noise in the medium propagates into the demodulated AM signal. It doesn't into a demodulates FM signal.

Comment: @EJP: An ideal AM receiver should multiply an incoming signal by a sinusoidal reference waves that's in phase with it and then low-pass filter the result.  By my understanding, however, most receivers work by mixing the incoming wave with a reference and then using a diode-based peak detector on the result.  This is much easier, and it will work to detect signal, but it will be more effective at detecting noise.